# Unreachable code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

What does the following mean?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
Unreachable Code    
at mycode.sample.main(sample.java:24)
```

I'm hoping I can find the line where the error occurred. I thought "24" is the line, but I only have 23 lines of code in my project.

Here's the project code

```
package mycode;
import java.io.*;

public class sample {
  int first;
  int second;

  public sample (int fir,int sec)
  {
    fir = first;
    sec = second;
  }

  public void add()
  {
    System.out.println(first+second);       
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int f = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    // int s =  Integer.parseInt(reader.r   eadLine());
    sample sample2 = new sample(f,100);
    sample2.add();
  } 
}
```

I would like to understand this error message.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code is unreachable; meaning you probably have a statement after an infinite loop.

Comment: @JoshM. Not necessarily. There can be other circumstances also.

Comment: @RohitJain Just making an educated guess, :P

Comment: Also, in your constructor, `fir = first` and `sec = second` should both be the other way around (in other words, it should be `first = fir` and `second = sec`).

Comment: I only want to understand the message of the error. Or at least have the line that has it.

Comment: @Dennis yup didn't noticed that XD

Comment: I tried it again from scratch and it now worked. It's kinda odd why it didn't work the first three times. Thanks for your advices anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first message, `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:`means your code does not compile. You need to identify the error and fix it.
Modern IDEs e.g. Eclipse, Netbeans, etc flag compile errors. They can help you to quickly identify the source.

The second error:

```
Unreachable Code
at mycode.sample.main(sample.java:24
```

means that the code at line 24 will never be reached.

Here is an example of unreachable code:

```
public void doSomething() {
    if (true) {
        return;
    }
    // All code below here is considered unreachable code
    doSomething()
}
```

Comment: But my project have only 23 lines.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your constructor, from:

```
public sample (int fir,int sec)
{
    fir = first;
    sec = second;
}
```

to:

```
public sample (int fir,int sec)
{
    first = fir;
    second = sec;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've just done that. The "Unreachable code" disappeared. But the rest is still there.

Comment: What rest? There are more errors? I just tried your code and it runs fine with me...

Comment: No not mor errors, only the line "unrechable code goes away". Like this:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at mycode.sample.main(sample.java:24)

Comment: How about copying your fixed code to a new project and running it again?

Comment: I created three projects to try this code. Still none worked. I'm began to think this must be because of eclipse but I tried other projects with I made earlier and they still worked.

Comment: I tried it again from scratch and it now worked. It's kinda odd why it didn't work the first three times. Thanks for your suggestions. :D